# Given an array of integers, how do I find the sum of its elements with some simple constraints in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum, reduce

To find the sum of array's elements
I have tried this approach however the output comes undefined instead of an integer

constraints are `array.length > 0` && `array[i] <= 1000`

```html
function simpleArraySum(ar) {
    let acc = 0;
    for (let i = 0; ar.length; i++) {
        if (ar.length > 0 && ar[i] <= 1000) {
            acc += ar[i]
        } else {
            return
        }
    }
    return acc;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What should happen instead? Currently, you’re just exiting the function when the constraints don’t hold.

Comment: It's as simple as removing the `else` block since it's unnecessary.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#sum_of_values_in_an_object_array

Comment: `return arr.filter(val => val<=1000).reduce((acc, val) => acc+=val);`

Comment: What should happen if the condition is not met?

Comment: @sumairq ... At SO it is considered to be a nice gesture from the one who got help, to accept the answer which was the most helpful in solving the OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you only need to check that the length of the array is positive once since it will remain constant.

You can just return null if your conditions aren't met:

```
function simpleArraySum(ar) {
    if(ar.length <= 0){
       return null;
    }
    let acc = 0;
    for(let i = 0; ar.length; i++){
       if(ar[i] <= 1000){
          acc += ar[i]
       }
       else{
          return null;
       }
    }
    return acc;
}
```

Comment: Based on the constrain that the number to be added up is just all numbers lower than 1000, it can possibly have negative values in the array to be added up. So, the use of -1 is inappropriate for the `else`.

Comment: PatrickEvans fixed and @DhanaD. it says array[i] <= 1000, not the sum <= 1000

Comment: It's indeed that case, but suppose there's array like this: `[2, 3, -4, -1, -1]`, the sum of that array is `-1` and it's the same as the invalid array condition you give in your code, wasn't it? But yeah, you already fixed it to `null` which is appropriate for this case.

Comment: @DhanaD. oh sorry I misinterpreted your comment. I already accounted for this in my edit.

Comment: It's a typo in the first validation, you only changed the second one to null

Answer (score 1):

Initially check to see if the argument passed into the function [is an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) and has elements in it. If not return from the function, otherwise make the calculation, and then return the value.

```js
function simpleArraySum(ar) {
  if (!Array.isArray(ar) || !ar.length) return 'Not a valid array';
  let acc = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    if (ar[i] <= 1000) acc += ar[i];
  }
  return acc;
}

console.log(simpleArraySum([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(simpleArraySum([]));
console.log(simpleArraySum([10, 1, 2, 100, 1001]));
console.log(simpleArraySum('string'));
console.log(simpleArraySum([10, 1, 2, 100, 1000]));
```

Comment: be aware about one condition ... `ar[i] <= 1000` instead of `ar.length <= 1000`

Comment: It's been a long day @PeterSeliger. Thanks for spotting that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to dynamically add elements of an array. All you need is a function that will accumulate values (`sumSmallNumbers` in my example below), and a starting value (which in this case is 0). It is vary handy yet not easiest concept to understand, but once learned becomes a lifesaver from time to time.

```js
const myArray = Array.from({length: 3}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500)); // creates an array of 3 elements with random numbers
console.log(`Array elements: `, String(myArray));

function simpleArrSum(arr) {
  if(!arr.length) { // this check is not needed if you're sure to receive an array
  
    return 0; 
  }
  const sum = arr.reduce(
    function sumSmallNumbers(accumulator, current) {
      return (current <= 1000 ? accumulator + current : accumulator); // Conditional (ternary) operator, also very usefull!
    },
    0
  );
  
  return sum;
 }

console.log(`Sum of elements that are less then 1000: `, simpleArrSum(myArray));
```

Comment: There is no way to know if the array is valid

Comment: Even though I wasn't one who give downvote, but the constraint is `x <= 1000` not `x <1000`.

Comment: @iunfixit  from question's perspective - it is. If it has length == 0 it will return 0, which is the requirement as far as can understand ("result should be integer").
If you're saying that the variable needs to have proper type - you should probably make sure proper types are used in your code, and not confuse reader of the funcion with unnecessary polimorphism. But I've expanded my code to suit your need :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function arraySum(arr){
  if(arr.length > 0){
    const sum = arr.reduce((a,i) => {
      if (i <= 1000){
        return a + i
      }
      else{
        return a
      }
    })
    return sum 
  }
}
arr = [2,4,3,5,3 , 1002, 34, 34 , 34,34 , -150]
console.log(arraySum(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

Computing the total of an *all numbers* array is amongst the most stressed examples of how to utilize [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). The OP just needs to include the correct constraint(s) / condition(s) into the reducing callback function ...

```js
function aggregateConditionedTotal(total, int) {
  return total + ((int <= 1000) ? int : 0);
}
const arr = [];

console.log(
  (arr.length > 0)
    ? arr.reduce(aggregateConditionedTotal, 0)
    : null
);
console.log(
  [1001].reduce(aggregateConditionedTotal, 0)
);

console.log(
  [1, 2, 3, 1001, 4].reduce(aggregateConditionedTotal, 0)
);
console.log(
  [1, 2, 3, 1000, 4].reduce(aggregateConditionedTotal, 0)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Here is another implementation of a possible reducer. From the Q it became not that clear whether the OP wants to entirely invalidate a total as soon as an item does not meet a criteria. The beneath code does so ...

```js
function aggregateConditionedTotal(total, int) {
  return ((total !== null) && (int <= 1000))
    ? (total + int)
    : null;
}
const arr = [];

console.log(
  (arr.length > 0)
    ? arr.reduce(aggregateConditionedTotal, 0)
    : null
);

console.log(
  [1, 2, 3, 1001, 4].reduce(aggregateConditionedTotal, 0)
);
console.log(
  [1, 2, 3, 1000, 4].reduce(aggregateConditionedTotal, 0)
);

console.log(
  [1000].reduce(aggregateConditionedTotal, 0)
);
console.log(
  [1001].reduce(aggregateConditionedTotal, 0)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find the sum of numbers in the input array, you just have to loop index from 0 to `array.length`. Inside the `for` loop, you are putting as

```
let i = 0; ar.length; i++
```

Here the condition for loop is `ar.length`, which is always truthy. You should make the condition more specific as `i < ar.length`. So this will loop only till 0 to `ar.length`.

**Working fiddle with fixed logic as above**

```js
function simpleArraySum(ar) {
  let acc = 0;
  // Check the index is less than length of array
  for (let i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    // Your special condition
    if (ar.length > 0 && ar[i] <= 1000) {
      acc += ar[i]
    }
  }
  return acc;
}
console.log(simpleArraySum([1, 2, 3]));
```

**Why your code is throwing undefined?**

In your code, you are running for loop with

```
let i = 0; ar.length; i++
```

Here the condition is mentioned as `ar.length`, this is true always (Provided length of array is greater than 0). So this is a kind of infinite loop, which never ends. You are making this infinite loop as a finite, by putting the return statement inside the else block. This return doesnot provide a value, so the return value is undefined. This return exits from the function with a value undefined. This is why your code reurns undefined.

Your array starts looping from index 0. After index 0, 1 to the length of array, after that the value of `ar[i]` will be undefined and for that value `ar[i] <= 1000` will be false. This will move the execution to else block and return undefined. Please find the below fiddle with console ststement added.

Your code execution with console statement.

```js
function simpleArraySum(ar) {
    let acc = 0;
    for (let i = 0; ar.length; i++) {
        if (ar.length > 0 && ar[i] <= 1000) {
            acc += ar[i]
        } else {
            // Exiting here
            console.log('Im exiting here, I dont provide a retun value');
            return;
        }
    }
    return acc;
}
console.log(simpleArraySum([1, 2, 3]));
```